# dynamic linker fails to find symbol at runtime after updating to Xcode 15

Tags: netcdf, dyld, rpath, xcode15

After upgrading to Xcode 15, I have been having problems with dynamic libraries linking at run time. I compiled netcdf-c from source using cmake and installed it in `/usr/local`.

Consider the simple test program.

```
#import <netcdf.h>

int main() {
    nc_strerror(0);
}
```

I can build and link it using the following command.

`clang -o test main.c -lnetcdf -L/usr/local/lib`

Everything compiles fine but I get a runtime error when running.

```
% ./test 
dyld[67988]: Symbol not found: _nc_strerror
  Referenced from: <31EE4C15-A028-32F2-8524-123CC396EB82> /Users/***/Desktop/test/test
  Expected in:     <no uuid> unknown
zsh: abort      ./test
```

I can confirm that the symbol is present in `libnetcdf.dylib`.

```
 % nm libnetcdf.dylib| grep _nc_strerror
0000000000006070 T _nc_strerror
```

I cannot figure out why this isn't loading this symbol. The only thing I can guess it make be related to needing to disable `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH` when build the HDF5 library because I was getting an `@rpath` error with the szip library.

```
% make
[  0%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/H5detect.dir/H5detect.c.o
[  0%] Linking C executable ../bin/H5detect
[  0%] Built target H5detect
[  0%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/H5make_libsettings.dir/H5make_libsettings.c.o
[  0%] Linking C executable ../bin/H5make_libsettings
[  0%] Built target H5make_libsettings
[  0%] Create H5lib_settings.c
dyld[69160]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libszip.2.1.dylib
  Referenced from: <893565BE-D306-3437-AA9A-67027F43FC49> /Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/bin/H5make_libsettings
  Reason: tried: '/Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/lib/libszip.2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/bin/libszip.2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/bin/../lib/libszip.2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/bin/libszip.2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/lib/libszip.2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/bin/libszip.2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/bin/../lib/libszip.2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/bin/libszip.2.1.dylib' (no such file)
/bin/sh: line 1: 69160 Abort trap: 6           /Users/***/Libraries/hdf5-1.14.2/build/bin/H5make_libsettings H5lib_settings.c
make[2]: *** [src/gen_SRCS.stamp2] Error 134
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gen_hdf5-static.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Also I build the szip library from source using cmake and installed it in `/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

They have a new linker that might be the problem. Maybe this from the release notes of Xcode can help?
"A new linker has been written to significantly speed up static linking. It’s the default for all macOS, iOS, tvOS and visionOS binaries and anyone using the “Mergeable Libraries” feature. The classic linker can still be explicitly requested using -ld64, and will be removed in a future release."

Comment: I tried this it gave me a warning `ld: warning: -ld64 is deprecated, use -ld_classic instead`

Comment: Using -ld_classic didn't make any difference for me, seeing the same result. Symbol not found, `Expected in:     <no uuid> unknown`

Comment: Running with `DYLD_PRINT_SEARCHING=1` seems to indicate the problem is dyld not handling @rpath quite the same way anymore, at least for these libraries in `/usr/local`?

Comment: Not libtool, since I am seeing the same thing in both autotools and cmake builds.

Comment: Nothing to do with cmake or autotools, just like you, I can turn over a very small example program, and it fails because `/usr/local/lib` is no longer on the dyld search list. What I don't understand is what change you and I made that caused this (pretty important) change in behavior.

Comment: So far the best workaround I have found is `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib` but this still doesn't work for all my cases. The man page says this is its default setting, but it doesn't seem to be working that way for us.

Comment: I'm fairly convinced it's not the linker but a change in the behaviour of dyld we are seeing. Why it would crop up in the middle of a stable release cycle is beyond me. But executables that used to correctly find their dependencies in `/usr/local/lib` no longer do so, seemingly correlated with updating to XCode 15.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here. It seems to no longer look for frameworks in /Library/Frameworks. I get this message when trying to run my application via Xcode:
dyld[2493]: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2

It did work without any problems before updating to Xcode 15. I installed no other updates in between.

Comment: I tried downgrading the command-line-tools, but it didn't fix it, unfortunately. Maybe the 15 upgrade overwrote something that 14 didn't touch. For cases where you don't have children forking or shells spawning children, setting the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` low enough down in your environment gets many things working again. 

The error message `Expected in:     <no uuid> unknown` is so obscure and opaque it feels like a bug.

Comment: I agree that this feels like a bug. As a quick workaround I added /Library/Frameworks to the Runpath Search Paths of my target in Xcode.

Comment: Just a quick note: The very same application built with Xcode 14 still correctly searches the fallback rpath on the same system. The problem only occurs after building with Xcode 15.